# How do i convert a React Native template into a project and run it?

Tags: react-native, templates

This is the template i am trying to use,

https://www.instamobile.io/app-templates/food-app-template

https://github.com/instamobile/recipes-app-react-native

I have downloaded it into a folder named FoodApp and ran npm install.
Then i run npx react-native start. After that I open another command prompt and run npx react-native run-android. It shows error

> error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native
> project? If your Android files are located in a non-standard location
> (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), consider setting
> `project.android.sourceDir` option to point to a new location. Run CLI
> with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app uses the [Expo](https://expo.dev/) toolset and requires `expo-cli` to be installed before it can be ran. You can install it with `npm install -g expo-cli` followed by `expo start` to run the app.

Comment: Yes after install expo i am able to run it, though it would be better if there is a way to run it with npx react-native run-android i am used to. Thanks!